# Pandas groupby specific range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use groupby to group a dataset by a specific range. In the following dataframe, I'd like to groupby the max_speed which is above 150 and also count the number of items that are above 150.

An example dataset is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
     [
       ("bird", "Falconiformes", 250.0),
       ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 250.0),
       ("mammal", "Carnivora", 180.2),
       ("mammal", "Primates", 159.0),
       ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
 index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
 )
```

What I've tried is:

```
df[['max_speed'] > 150].groupby('max_speed').size()
```

Expected output:

```
max_speed     count
180.2          1
250.0          2
159.0          1
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: `df.groupby(df['max_speed'] > 150).size()`

Comment: you have a typo I reckon : `df[df['max_speed'] > 150].groupby('max_speed').size()` instead of `df[['max_speed'] > 150].groupby('max_speed').size()` you miss the boolean indexing

Comment: @anky your solution works. Cheers. If you'd like to put is as an answer so I can accept it.